# Miss/Break A Curfew

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning

I have a question about the usage of the verb "*miss*" [here](http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/eye-on-football/24792374/report-20-cowboys-players-missed-friday-curfew-in-london):

> Report: 20 Cowboys players ***missed Friday curfew*** in London

"*Missed the curfew*" seems to be similar to "*missed the meeting*".  Would "*broke the curfew*" be better?

Comment: Why do you think one might be "better" than the other?

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to think that the sense of missing curfew implies they were late, with every intent of being there at some point.

Breaking curfew implies wilful disobedience; no intent whatsoever to return at the correct time.

The headline itself gives the impression they were enjoying their visit to London too much to want to return at the correct time.

Conversely, "Report: 20 Insurgents broke Friday's curfew in the strife-torn city" gives a whole world of difference as to intent.

Answer (score 0):

Both the terms "Missed curfew" and "broke curfew" are acceptable while the phrase "broke **the** curfew" sounds verbose. However, "missed **the** meeting" is correct.

In the first usage, we are saying that they missed the appropriate time. The second is similar to "breaking the law". I have heard both being used, but I tend to prefer "broke curfew".